# Use MySQL match against matching from beginning of column only

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing, full-text-search

I've added a Fulltext Index on a huge tabel to speedup my search but can't find a soluteion for my Problem

I've a Line like:

```
ID|TITLE|SOMETHING ELSE|
```

Let's say in this table I've following rows:

```
 10|Some text|fdsfsd|
 11|More some text|dfdsfsdffsdfsdf|
```

And I want to match only the row which begins wit `"Some text"`.

Then I used in the past for small Tables something like

`WHERE TITLE like 'Some text%'`.

But how can I hanle exactly this with match against to have the advantage of my fulltext index because with a query like these:

`WHERE match(TITLE) against('Some text')` I'll get both rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `FULLTEXT` index for the large-scale matching, and then refine your results, for example like this:

```
WHERE match(TITLE) against('Some text')
  AND TITLE like 'Some text%'
```

This will let the FULLTEXT system narrow down the match choices before applying the other criterion.

Please be sure to examine the performance of this and validate it by doing `EXPLAIN` when your database is fully populated, though. Sometimes the optimizer makes strange choices.

Comment: Thanks a lot initially reducing is the key ;)